# Master to Master Replication: Clogged until restart

Tags: mysql, replication

I have got master - to master replication installed.

It all works fine, until you break the link between two servers.

Once it's broken the data won't go from one to another if it exceeds some kind of limit.

Max_packet size is set to 500mb.

However, if you restart the server (mysqld) where the data is clogged (on secondary) it will push it throught.

Nothing in the log file related to this.. Any ideas?

Configuration for primary:

```
[mysqld]
innodb_file_per_table=1
server-id=6935500
log_bin=mysql-bin
binlog_format=ROW
log_error=/var/log/mysql-bin.err
#binlog_do_db=devjump_dev
binlog_do_db=crm_live
max_allowed_packet=500M
```

Configuration for secondary

```
[mysqld]
bind-address=0.0.0.0
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
server-id=574271
log_bin=mysql-bin.log
binlog_format=ROW
binlog_do_db=crm_live

max_allowed_packet=500M
log_error=/var/log/mysql-bin.err
relay-log=mysqld-relay-bin
```

So apparently, after we break a link between these two some big packets are not being pushed into the binlog... From Primary to Secondary.

Thanks Guys,

Roman

Answer (score 0):

After spending lots of hours reading and searching I have discovered that there was an issue with slave-net-timeout

It was defaulted to 3600 so it took 1 hour for the Secondary to find out there was a lag in the connection.

Resetting this to 60 seconds helped big time.

Hopefully someone might find this post useful and it will save their time.

Comment: Would you like to tell me how to set the timeout?

Comment: slave-net-timeout  ins my.cnf file